# Whats the best way to map an integer to an object.with the object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap, key, mapping

Hey this may be a silly question but while i can use the put function to map objects to an integer:

```
product Tuna = new product(1, nutrientsIn);

product Milk = new product(0, nutrientsIn2);

HashMap<product, Integer> productQuantity = new HashMap<product, Integer>();

productQuantity.put(Tuna, 2);

productQuantity.put(Milk, 4);

Diet.totalNutrients(productQuantity);
```

If I try to access the value using the name of the object as a key:

```
System.out.printf("%d\n", productQuantity.get(Milk));
```

I get an error:cannot find symbol. Which I assume means it's looking for the Milk variable.

Is this the right way to go about this and if so how could I or is there a better way.

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` in your `Product` class?

Comment: I haven't. I've tried now but it cannot find it. Could you explain any further what you mean?

Comment: Generally in Java, objects strt with lower-case letter (tuna) and classes start with capital letters (Tuna).

Answer (score 0):

1. *error:cannot find symbol*

   - You are getting this because you are using variable *MILK* outside its scope.
2. Alternate way

   - You can make a Enum for *product*

---

Code for your current approach

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product Tuna = new Product(1, "nutrientsIn");

        Product Milk = new Product(0, "nutrientsIn2");

        HashMap<Product, Integer> productQuantity = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();

        productQuantity.put(Tuna, 2);

        productQuantity.put(Milk, 4);

//        Diet.totalNutrients(productQuantity);

        // Use this if in same block
        System.out.printf("%d\n", productQuantity.get(Milk));
        // Use this if in some other block (where getting the error)
        Product makeMilkObject = new Product(0, "nutrientsIn2");
        System.out.printf("%d\n", productQuantity.get(makeMilkObject));
    }
}

class Product{
    int key;
    String nutrient;
    Product(int key, String nutrient){
        this.key = key;
        this.nutrient = nutrient;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getNutrient() {
        return nutrient;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this.key == ((Product)obj).getKey()) && (this.getNutrient().equals(((Product) obj).getNutrient()));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but I'm trying to use the product object as the key in the map and the value being an integer. I'd rather the quanity variable not be stored as a class variable.

Comment: @ras64 ok.. so I am editing my answer. I overlooked this. I supposed that you are storing the productKeyArgument as the Value at map.

Comment: @ras64 You can also use Enums, for this

Comment: Yeah I'm able to do this when the value comes from the class I'm using as a key. However I'm not sure if it's possible to have a seperate primitive as a value. If so could you recommend any other ways of achieveing a similiar result?